# {MAC OS BIG SUR} Getting "Network Response Timed Out" Error while scanning qr code from expo app

Tags: android, expo, react-native, macos-big-sur

[image]
[image]

I am getting this error while trying to run my react native expo managed app through expo android app.

I already explored the stackoverflow for similar questions and i also found some answers but none of them worked for me.

**I am using Mac OS Big Sur & i think this is the reason why other's answers didn't worked for me because mostly all of the answers were for the windows os**

Please help me out with this issue.

(PS: I already tried set REACT_NATIVE...=192.. thing but that also didn't worked out)